# how can i make a loop using javascript and symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, loops

Actually i'm using a script to get all the categories' ID and i want to stick them all in a variable as you can see in the code below ! i guess i have to add a loop but i can't see how can i do that ! any help please !

```
$('#generer').click(function() {
        {% for group in groups %}
        {% for categorie in group.categories %}
            var just = $('#{{ categorie.id }}').val().toUpperCase();
            var trame = "";
            for (i = 0; i < just.length; i++) {
                trame += "{{ categorie.title }}" + just + "\n";
            }
            {#var trame = "{{ categorie.title }} " + just + "\n";#}
            {#trame += "{{ categorie.title }}" + just + "\n";#}
            $('#resultat-trame').text(trame);
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you need an Array. Try this:

```
var array = [];
array.push(just);
```

Comment: i think i have to add those ligne before my : "var just = $('#{{ categorie.id }}').val().toUpperCase();"

Comment: If you do array.push(just); before then variable would be undefined.